# Additional resources directories for images in Maven site

Tags: java, maven, asciidoc

For a Maven site, the standard image directory is `src/site/resources/images`.

Unfortunately, my asciidoc editor copies images to `src/site/asciidoc/images`. Can I somehow add this directory to the site resources (as in the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html))?

Comment: Do you mean copying the resources finally to `/target/site/resources/images`?

Answer (score 1):

To copy all resources to an outputDirectory, you can simply specify following in your pom.xml-

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/site/resources/images</outputDirectory>
          <resources>          
            <resource>
              <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>              
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

***Sources***  - [Example from the plugin itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584291/additional-resources-directories-for-images-in-maven-site)